# C# Cast result from double multiplication which give wrong result

Tags: c#, casting

Can anyone explain this?

As the picture shows after multiplication, I should get 29.0, cast to short which should have given me 29 but I got 28

[image]

I did research on casting, but did not really get an answer

Comment: It may be related to double number representation rather than casting

Comment: It's prolly 28.99999 but by casting you just ignore decimal places

Comment: `var b = Convert.ToInt16(a);` would not truncate the `.99999` but round to 29.

Comment: Please don't use images of code but add as (formatted) text

Comment: 0.0029 is really 0.00289999999999999980015985556747182272374629974365234375 (according to [DoubleConverter](https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/DoubleConverter.cs)

Answer (score 1):

please note that 'a' is declared as a double data type, which is a floating-point type that can store fractional numbers. when you assign the value of 'a' to variable 'b', which is declared as a short data type, a type conversion occurs.
in this situation the decimal part of 'a' gets truncated because the short data type can only hold whole numbers within a specific range. as a result 'b' will have a value of 28 instead of 29.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am still confused The result after multiplication should be 29.0 even if type conversion truncated happens. I should still get 29 right?

Comment: This is the expected behavior when casting a floating-point number to an integral type.
If you want to preserve the decimal part and obtain the value 29, you should consider using a data type that supports decimal values, such as decimal, float, or double.